# Gson different behavior for generated apk and debug mode

Tags: android, json, gson

I try to parse data which i am getting from notification bundle:

```
String intervalsData = data.getString(ARG_INTERVAL, "[]");
Type intervalListType = new TypeToken<List<Interval>>() {}.getType();
List<Interval> intervalList = ConnectionUtils.dataFromString(intervalsData, intervalListType);
```

Here is example of data:

```
"[{
  \"StartDateTime\": \"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",
  \"EndDateTime\": \"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",
  \"Interval\": \"100000.0\"
}]"
```

dataFromString method:

```
public static <T> T dataFromString(String json, Type type) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat(Common.DateFormatKinds.ServerDateFormat.getValue())
                .create();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
```

Server date format is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`

Interval class:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Interval{
    public Date StartDateTime;
    public Date EndDateTime;
    public double Interval;
}
```

When I upload an application from android studio to device, everything works fine.
But when I generate apk and upload it by hockeyapp, Gson parses array correctly, but fields in Interval item are null.

Comment: Are you using proguard? Gson needs field/method names to be intact and proguard changes them.

Comment: Yes, I am using proguard. What should I add?

Comment: On your proguard-rules.pro add `-keep class com.example.path.to.Interval {*;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `@Keep` annotation for `Interval` class, because proguard obfuscate all classes in signed apk and Gson can`t parse JSON to you model.:

```
import java.util.Date;
import android.support.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class Interval{
    public Date StartDateTime;
    public Date EndDateTime;
    public double Interval;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to the ProGuard configuration rules, in order to preserve the class name and it's public fields:

```
-keep class com.acme.Interval { public <fields>; }
```

using the `@Keep` annotation handles this at the code level; both methods are valid.